# How do I detect when a user closes a browser window, and send an AJAX request using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

What I want to do is save a JSON object in the localStorage. This object's value and structures will change depending how the user interacts with the website. When the user leaves (i.e. closes the browser window), the JSON object is saved to my database using an AJAX request.

I want to do this because I believe this will make the whole process much more faster, as the server is hit only once, after all the interactions are done. Is this feasible? Is there a way to do this using Javascript (or JQuery)? Am I looking at this in a completely wrong way? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To put json into localstorage encode it as a string (json.stringify()). You could use the window.beforeunload event to send it on browserclose, however, a user could simply close the window without sending the data to server

Comment: So if you want to reduce serverconnections, register a service worker that uploads the data in background (i think its possible). If registering fails you could do a fallback through sending the data to server on every change

Comment: Your plan is flawed. When the user closes the browser, a `beforeunload` event is fired, but there is no guarantee that the ajax request will be sent, or that anything at all will be done, before the browser actually closes.

Comment: Ah thanks, thats the confirmation I wanted.Time to try things differently.